# Sitecore WFFM MVC and field rules

Tags: sitecore, web-forms-for-marketers, sitecore7.2, personalization, sitecore-mvc

Im using Sitecore Webforms for marketers and MVC. Everything is working fine except if I try to setup a rule for a field.
In the example attached I expect the "test" field to always be hidden, but it doesnt work. Other types of conditions and rules doesnt work either.
Personalisation with conditional rules work fine on rendering level.

Im using Sitecore v7.2 and WFFM version 2.4.

After digging through the source my conclusion is that this is not supported with MVC. Is that true? Has anyone else made this work with MVC?

[image: Wffm with field rule]

Comment: Which revision of 2.4?   MVC was first supported in revision 140923

Comment: Update: I have created a support ticket at Sitecore and they are looking into it.

Comment: Any update on this one? I dont seem to find the rules tab as well

Comment: This is the last update from Sitecore (over a year ago):

"Thank you for informing us about this issue in the WFFM module.  We reproduced it in our environment and registered it as a bug.
During the investigation we didn’t find an easy way to solve this issue. We recommend you to wait until it is fixed in one of the upcoming versions of the WFFM module.
We are sorry for the inconveniences."